# Segmentation Fault for Merge function of Merge Sort

Tags: c++11, mergesort

My task is to implement just the merge function of merge sort algorithm.My idea is to create an auxilliary array to store the sorted values.I have mainted 2 pointers,one for left sorted array and other for right sorted array.

I am having difficulty in figuring out why am I getting segmentation fault?

```
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{

 int temp[r-l+1];int count=0;
 int *ptr1=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
 int * ptr2=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
 ptr1=&arr[l];
 ptr2=&arr[m+1];
 while(ptr1!=(&arr[m+1]) && ptr2!=NULL)
 {
     if(*ptr1>=*ptr2)
     {
      temp[++count]=*ptr2;
      ptr2++;
     }
     else 
     {
         temp[++count]=*ptr1;
         ptr1++;
     }
 }
 if(ptr1==&arr[m+1])
 {
     while(ptr2)
     {
        temp[++count]=*ptr2;
        ptr2++;
     }
 }
 if(ptr2==NULL)
 {
  while(ptr1!=&arr[m+1])
     {
        temp[++count]=*ptr1;
        ptr1++;
     }   
 }
 for(int i=0;i<r-l+1;i++)
 {
     arr[i]=temp[i];
 }
}
```

Input:
2

5

4 1 3 9 7

10

10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Expected Output:

1 3 4 7 9

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

My Output:Segmentation fault

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). "What is wrong with my code?" questions are good ones until you've made the question smaller. Also, have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, these lines for malloc are not necessary

```
 int *ptr1=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
 int * ptr2=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
 ptr1=&arr[l];
 ptr2=&arr[m+1];
```

and can be changed to

```
 int *ptr1=&arr[l];
 int * ptr2=&arr[m+1];
```

The other problem is that the test for `NULL` for `ptr2` does not work since the address past the last element is not `NULL`.

Comment: You mean to say that after ptr2 reaches end of the list then further incrementing it will point to some other address which may not be NULL.Am I right?